# What is a "high-level conversation"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, conversation

Recently I was told by a potential interviewer for a job that we would be having a "high-level conversation" soon.

I assumed at the time that she just meant a conversation with a higher-up, e.g., her boss, but suddenly am not so sure.

So I'm curious. Have you heard that term before, and what does it mean?

Comment: Do you really mean "interviewee", i.e. "person I will interview"? Unless I'm missing something, "interviewer" would make more sense.

Comment: I think it could mean either, depending on the interviewer: it could be a conversation at a higher level of the company's hierarchy, or about more advanced or more specific subjects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A high-level conversation is one where you discuss generalities instead of focusing on details.

Comment: That makes sense, she did say shortly after that we'd be discussing my interests... which I suspect will be considered in a very general sort of manner.

Comment: Please could you provide some more explanation or a reference to back up your answer? I'm having a really hard time believing this is correct, except maybe only in an ironic sense.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: This interpretation is how I and the people I speak to use it. At a high level you can see the big picture, at a low level you can see the details. It's basically a metaphor. I don't have any authoritative references but these two links use it in this way (in the context of systems design): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_and_low_level http://urbanixconsulting.com/glossary.php

Comment: @Jimi Oke Software development is the same. A high level language (.NET, Java) you don't have to deal with the details of memory management, hardware interfaces, or much else. Lower level (C/C++ down to Assembly) languages you are concerned with all the details. I assumed this was pretty much standard English when heard elsewhere on different subjects. Low level = details, high level = bigger picture.

Comment: Mr. Shiny and New and @Aequitarum Custos: Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: Mr. Shiny and New's answer is correct. A "High-level conversation" means to provide general information and not specific to details. An overview in a sense focusing on the general idea and not the technicalities.

Answer (score 2):

"High level" here normally refers to the status of the participants. When you read in the paper that "The US and Germany are holding high-level talks," the meaning is that these involve persons on both sides at the upper levels of government, up to and including the president, prime minister, etc.

Comment: About political contexts I’d agree, but for a job interview, especially for any kind of technical job, I think that Mr. Shiny and New’s interpretation is much more likely.

Comment: +1 This is what I always interpreted it to mean as well and [The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/high-level) says the same thing. We'll never know what the interviewer meant, though. Based on the other answer, using high-level to mean discussing generalities seems to be fairly common too:)

Comment: By the way, I've never, not once, heard "high-level" used in the sense described by Mr Shiny.

Comment: @TheRaven it is "high-level" in the "50,000 ft (or km) view" sense.